# Getting month's end data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Python.

I’m trying to figure out how to get the month’s end ‘Adj Close’ rows for each data set (aapl, intc, ebay and amzn).

Here’s what I have done:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day,MonthEnd

import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2013,10,28)
end = datetime.datetime(2018,10,28)
aapl = web.DataReader('AAPL','yahoo',start,end)
intc = web.DataReader('INTC','yahoo',start,end)
ebay = web.DataReader('EBAY','yahoo',start,end)
amzn = web.DataReader('AMZN','yahoo',start,end)
```

I put in the DataFrame

```
amazon = amzn
amzn = pd.DataFrame({'AMZN': amazon['Adj Close']})
```

I wanted the data to show only the month end’s data, so I did this, but it’s giving me an error:

```
amzn = amzn.loc[pd.date_range(start, end, freq='BM')]
```

How do I get to show only the month’s end?

I also wanted to create a table, with dates as the index, showing all stock’s adj close during the month’s end.

I tried this and didn’t work (it says that there are duplicate keys):

```
alldata = pd.merge(aapl,intc,ebay,amzn)
```

I know that `‘BM’` gives me month’s end, but I can’t seem to find a way to use it.

I’m scratching my head and have been looking; I can’t find the answer.

Comment: do you only want the days that are also months end days? you could do a join on the datetime index.

Comment: I want the latest day of the month that has values (Feb 28, 2015, March 30... ).

Comment: @davedwards oh I see... yes will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your example, given a DataFrame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'AMZN': amzn['Adj Close']})
```

You could try using the `is_month_end` function:

```
data.loc[amzn['Adj Close'].index.is_month_end]
```

This will produce:

```
AMZN
Date    
2013-10-31  364.029999
2013-12-31  398.790009
2014-01-31  358.690002
...
```

Notice that it is returning results for the last day of the month, if it has a value.

To get the *latest day* in the month with a value (but not necessarily the *last day* of the month), you might try:

```
data.reset_index().loc[d2['Date']
    .groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index)
    .to_period('M')).idxmax()]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked ->  data = pd.DataFrame({'AMZN': amzn['Adj Close']}). I can't seem to make the date.reset_index to work. I'm still figuring it out :).

Answer (score 0):

If the date is your index and you want to subset your dataframe with the latest date in the month, try this: `df[df.index.day == df.index.days_in_month]`